# Get CPU usage from Azure API with Java

Tags: java, api, azure, cpu

I have a simply program in Java and I want to get some information from the Windows Azure Service Management REST API Reference : the number of instances and the CPU usage.

For the number of instances, I found what I want but not for the CPU usage.

For the number of instances, I do a Https Get request, the API sends me an XML response and I process this file for the information I need ([Get Hosted Service Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460806.aspx)). I don't know if it is possible for the CPU usage too. For now, I didn't find anything in the msdn site or with Google.

Someone can help me please?

One remarks : I can't test anything regarding the Azure API because my account is disabled so I would have to trust you until my account is available again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve CPU utilization or other performance counters, you need to access WADPerformanceCountersTable in the storage account that is setup to store diagnostic data.

Here is the help page to help with connecting Java to table storage:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/how-to-guides/table-service/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will test that when I will have my account enable again

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SIGAR - System Information Gatherer And Reporter](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) it seems to be a well supported and documented library to gather system information.

It has a [getCpuUsage](http://www.hyperic.com/support/docs/sigar/org/hyperic/sigar/CpuTimer.html#getCpuUsage%28%29) function

Comment: It seems to be an API to have the CPU of your machine.
Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I want the CPU usage of the instances running for a Cloud Service in Azure

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure SDK for Java is actually open source, if you really want this feature to be built in, you might want to consider contributing to it following its guideline. http://windowsazure.github.io/guidelines.html#contributing